# Hiding and showing tab bar in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I'm looking to create a setup form for my application - and I wanted to use a tab form to keep my logic on the one form since it's very simple rather than many of them. Is there a way to remove the tab navigation UI up top and allow me to only progress it programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at user controls. They cover pretty much what you want.

Just create a user control for each view. It only consists of the controls you want to have on each tab page anyway. Then you can hide/show the user control you want and you do not have a full blown form for each view.

Look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx